# How can I have good quality when I get pictures?

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide

I want to create user profile. I am using Firebase to make authentication and get profile picture but when I get profile picture, quality is not good.
I used Glide to load image

```
Glide.with(this)
                .load(this.getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl())
                .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
                .into(imageViewProfile);
```

My Image view:

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="113dp"
    android:layout_height="102dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

How can I fix it? I already try to use Picasso but that didn't work.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using **RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()**, try using CircleImageView.

Import this -

`compile "de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0"`

in your layout file

```
 <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_80sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_80sdp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/prof_pic"
        app:civ_border_width="@dimen/_2sdp"
        app:civ_border_color="#bf0000"
        android:elevation="@dimen/_2sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_60sdp"
        />
```

and to load image

```
   Glide.with(getActivity()).load("url").placeholder(R.drawable.bluehead).into(Prof_Pic);
```

Comment: Did he asked about `CircleImageView`?

Comment: Dude look clearly he has written RequestOptions.circleCropTransform(). That why i gave him alternative.